# getting value of a coulmn subjected that it is filtered using three filters

Tags: python, pandas

I am in need to get the value of a cell in column subjected that it fulfill the requirement of equality  between three coulmn values

df_users header
USER_NAME   PhoneNumber CabinetTECode   ShelfNumber PeeringPointDescription InterfaceDesc   AdditionalInfo  CVLAN   TESVLAN

while df1 header
Timestamp   Message username    int bras    ae  svlan   cvlan

i need to filter using svlan then cvlan then ae by which df_users header TESVLAN,CVLAN,InterfaceDesc respectively and return the value of corresponding USER_NAME

i tried several times but all gives error

please support

for df_users

[image]

for d1

[image]

i want to check last three columns on df1 presence on df_users and return the corresponding value of USER_NAME

Comment: Show a piece of data please. That we can manipulate and find the best solution. Show the  output you are looking for.

Comment: @MárioCésarFracalossiBais done above